# React component error message using filter method

Tags: reactjs, filter

Why am I getting a `Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')` with the following React component?  (I can console.log "squads" and "weekNo" and get the correct results)

```
import React from "react";

const Weekly = ({ squads, weekNo }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {squads
          .filter((squad) => squad.division === "NFC North")
          .map((filteredDivision) => (
            <li>{filteredDivision}</li>
          ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>{weekNo}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Weekly;
```

Comment: Can you share the log of `squads` please ?

Comment: @john-g Did you checked if you are getting correct value of squads with type array ? I think squads is passed incorrectly or have initial value as undefined from the parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add some comments to your code.

```
        {squads
          // 1
          .filter((squad) => squad.division === "NFC North")
          // 2
          .map((filteredDivision) => (
            <li>{filteredDivision}</li>
          ))}
```

Assuming `squads` is an array like below,

```
  [{ division: 'a' }, { division: 'b' }]
```

After your statement 1, it gets all element with division set to "NFC North".

Now at your statement 2, remember it's still an array of objects. You can't print out an object directly. But you can print out one property of an object.

```
          .map((squad) => (
            <li>{squad.division}</li>
          ))
```

Hope this makes sense now.

NOTE: `filter` or `map` produces a new array.

Make sure the `squads` is valid at the first place. For example.

```
const Weekly = ({ squads, weekNo }) => {
  if (!squads) return null
  return (...)
```

Comment: This may be true, but it does not address the error in the question..

Comment: Add the first line `if (!squads) return null` as your first line in your component, it'll work :) I update the answer, read the last section then. In the first render, you haven't gotten your `squads` yet.

Comment: @windmaomao Yes, that did the trick!  Thanks.  With that help, let's see if I can do something that works.  This is my first React app, and I'm not quite grasping the React rules yet.

Comment: You are welcome @John, if you have any doubt, just use `console.log` in all places where you find suspicious ;)